# find all substrings matching the pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find all substrings like "something.somethingElse.get()" in a long string. I'm using match function in this way

```
myString.match(/\S+\.\S+\.get\(\)/);
```

It works, but returns only the first occurrence, so I have to split the string in some way to eliminate the firt part and repeat match again.
Is there a more efficient way to do this? I mean something like a search function that returns all substring in an array or an object

Comment: Are you looking for myString.split(".") ? That will work on strings though, not objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myString.match(/\S+\.\S+\.get\(\)/gi);`

You need to add *global* switch at the end of your regex.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match (thanx, vcsjones)

Comment: +1; and [relevant documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).